# First item on multiple update not working (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have multiple data that can be changed/updated one time through a checkbox. It is working, but when it has 2 or more data on the list the first data on it is not changing or updating, but others are working fine. It is working fine when the list has only 1 item.

This is my HTML

```
@foreach($allergies as $aller)

    <select name="tolerance[]" class="tol" id="tol" style="width:20%" disabled>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
    </select>

    <input type="checkbox" class="allergies" id="allergies" name="allergen[]" value="{{$aller->allergen_id}}">
    {{ $aller->allergen_name}}
    <br>

@endforeach
```

my controller..

```
public function update2(Request $request, $id){
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = $request->all();
    $tolerances = $data['tolerance'];
    foreach($tolerances as $tolerance)
    {
        $this->updateData($data['ua_id'], $user, $tolerance);
    }

    return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('id', 'user'));
}
```

and js script for enabling/disabling select box every time checkbox is changed

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tol').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $checkBox = $('.allergies');

        $checkBox.on('change',function(e){
            var $select = $(this).prev();
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                $select.removeAttr('disabled');
            }else{
                $select.attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

my updateData method in the controller

```
public function updateData($ua_id, $user, $tolerance_level)
{
    UserAllergen::updateOrCreate(
        ['ua_id' => $ua_id, 'user_id' => $user],
        ['tolerance_level'=> $tolerance_level]
    );
}
```

Comment: The front end part looks good, but maybe if you share `updateData` method it will be great, I think the problem is there

Comment: Im sorry if forgot

Comment: i already edited with code of updateData

Comment: from where ua_id comes i have not seen in html??